# How to move files from several directory to one directory

Tags: unix

There are subdirectories in output directory as below.
C123
C444
C555
CCC
C216
B123
TEST

I need to move all the files from directory C123,C444,C555 to folder TEST. Please advise

Answer (score 1):

you can run these commands;

```
mv ./C123/* ./TEST/
mv ./C444/* ./TEST/
mv ./C555/* ./TEST/
```